# Dropdown Filter - Language English Name

Tags: sxa, content-search

I am using SXA Search component and with that I want to use "Dropdown" filter which will have "Language" facets in the dropdown for the search items. I am able to achieve it by getting "_language" facet but it shows language code (i.e. en, fr-FR) in the dropdown.

Is there any way, I can show Language names instead of code (i.e. English, French, etc)? I want to use OOTB functionality if available.

Additionally, is there a way I can use Default filter value from dropdown on page load? It means, can I have "English" as default selection and search results accordingly on page load?

Please find the screenshot of existing dropdown is as below -

[image: Ref Image as below]

Answer (score 2):

Facet filters are using values for the index. If inside of the index, the `_language` field has language codes :

[image]

then you will see language codes in the dropdown. What can be done here:

- use custom field with language
- try to find an existing field which has full language name instead of code. I noticed that there is a field called `paresedlanguage`. I have no idea what it is, probably it is a Sitecore field but it has full language name. Try to use it.

Regarding having the filter pre-selected. There is no such option. If you want to have filter pre-selected while opening the page, the URL would need to contain that facet after the hash (e.g.: `#language=en`).